# Flutter TextField Android Hide/Restore Persist Value

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

I have a simple test app - `TextField` in a `Scaffold`.  On Android, after typing in a value, pressing the Home button, and then going back to/restoring the app, the value is reset to the initial value/state - not the typed value/state it was in right before pressing the home button (unless the keyboard is explicitly dismissed).

When running the same app on iOS, it works as expected - the value does not get reset (and the keyboard does not need to be dismissed first).  I've tried it with/without state, explicitly declaring a controller with a value, etc. - no dice.

**Sample code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'TextField Test App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  String textValue;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    textValue = "initial value";
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("TextField Text"),
      ),

      body: TextField(
        controller: TextEditingController(
          text: textValue
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

[Animation showing value being reset when keyboard is not dismissed, and value persistence after dismissing keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xs63P.jpg)